# Evaluate $\pi$ using $\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$

Tags: calculus, inequality, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I Have to evaluate $\pi$ using $\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$  with an error with no more than $10^{-10}$ using taylor approximation $ p_{2n-1}(x) \approx\arctan(x)$ . So, After manipulation, I get: $$\pi = 6 \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$$

Now, from a previous exercise: $$p_{2n-1}(x) \approx\arctan(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{(-1)^{k}x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} + R_{2n},$$
Where: $$R_{2n} = (-1^{n}) \int^x_0 \frac{t^{2n}}{1+t^2}\,dt$$

Since we want the error to be bound by $10^{-10}$, then we evaluate: $6|R_{2n}|$, which gives: $$6\int^x_0 \frac{t^{2n}}{1+t^2}\,dt \leq 10^{-10}$$

On the other hand, in this particular case $x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} $ and by the mean value theorem for integrals, I obtain: $$6\int^\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}_0 \frac{t^{2n}}{1+t^2}\,dt = \frac{6}{1+c^2}\int^\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}_0 t^{2n}\,dt$$
where $c \in [0,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} ]$. So, we choose the end points $c =0$ and  $c = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and after the integration and manipulation, I have:

$$\frac{6(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{2n+1}}{2n+1} \leq 10^{-10}$$

On the other hand: $\frac{1}{2n+1} < 1$, so $$\frac{6(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{2n+1}}{2n+1} < {6(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{2n+1}} \leq 10^{-10}$$

So, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} < 1$ and after some manipulations I get: $$6*3^{-n} \leq 10^{-10},$$ Hence: $$60,000,000,000 \leq 3^n$$ So, $n > 22$, not sure if this is the right approach guys.